# Find MongoDB document with reversed logic

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find, contains, projection

I am developing a web app using NodeJs and MongoDB. In the database I got a documents that look like this:

```
"user": {
  "_id": "525cd98ef8cf50b0006ebcf3",
  "name": "alex",
  "age": 25,
  "gender": "male"
},


"post": {
    "_id": "525d3917cb2a20c02380c527",
    "title": "Ride bike",
    "text": "want to ride bike",
    "audience": {
        "age": [ 20, 30 ],
        "gender": [ "male", female ]
    }
}
```

I need to find all posts with  user.age between post.audience.age ages and post.audience.gender  contains user.gender.

Comment: You store `user` and `post` in the same collection?

Comment: No, first I get user object, and then i need to find posts, that user can see, depending on his age and gender

Comment: if your 'user' and 'post' , both are in different collections , it means you have to find the posts on some static value of age and gender that would refer to a particular user. right?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, you are right. I need to find() all posts where 25 is between audience.age and audience.gender contains 'male'.

Comment: so 'post' is an array??

Comment: yes, im considering to change age from array to object, if it might help: age: { from: 20, to: 30 }